# Язык программирования С#. Деление на ноль в калькуляторе

Tags: c#, winforms, калькулятор, деление

здесь предоставлен код для калькулятора на языке программирования с#, windows forms. Какой код и где его надо добавить для того, чтобы при вводе "0" в значении в, выводился текст "на ноль делить нельзя" в label 6?

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace калькулятор
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            c = a + b;
            label3.Text = "cумма двух чисел = " + Convert.ToString(c);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            c = a - b;
            label4.Text = "вычетание двух чисел = " + Convert.ToString(c);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            c = a * b;
            label5.Text = "умножение двух чисел = " + Convert.ToString(c);
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            c = a / b;
            label6.Text = "деление двух чисел = " + Convert.ToString(c);
        }
      }
    } ```
````

Comment: `if (b != 0) { c = a / b; label6.Text = "деление двух чисел = " + Convert.ToString(c); } else label6.Text = "на ноль делить нельзя";` а тот код, что написан, вы точно сами писали? Вы же проходили ветвления `if`?

Comment: да, проходили. у меня проблемы именно с тем, куда вписать код

Comment: благодарю за помощь! ;)

Comment: код обычно вписывают туда, где он нужен.